# Compress a 2D array into a 1D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

i have a quad (2D array) which is composed of numbers which ranges from 0 to 255 
and the most frequent value of the array ( in my case 2) is the background value

i have to put all the values of the array except the background value ( i have to ignore all cases that contains a 2) in a 1D array with this arrangement

the line,the column,the value,the line,the next column,the next value

for example i have

```
{2,3,2,2},
{2,2,2,2},
```

in the 1D array it will be like `{ 1,2,3,}`

i added spaces to make it more readable

here is my array

```
int image1[MAXL][MAXC]=
{
    {2,3,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2},
    {2,255,2,2},
    {255,2,2,2},
    {2,255,2,2}
};
```

and the loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i<nbc;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<nbl;j++)
    {
        if (image1[j][i]==BackColor)
        {

        }
        else 
    }
}
```

nbc and nbl are respectively the number of columns and lines

thanks you for your help

EDIT : i completely failed my example i didn't ignored the 2, should be fine now

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is a strange **Compression** BTW in your example as you don't skip background.

Comment: i didn't tried that much i only have a loop that go through the 2D array

Comment: @EdoYouss - then show the loop and the 2D array

Comment: `else` with no body is going to give the compiler fits.

Comment: i'm new to c++ so i still don't know how to use std::vector :(

Comment: @EdoYouss - If you are new to C++ then forget all about C-style arrays and start learning about the containers. They were invented to make life simple.

Comment: @EdoYouss [c++ containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) - [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach using `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> result;
for (int i = 0; i<MAXL;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<MAXC;j++)
    {
        if (image1[i][j] != BackColor)  // Notice !=
        {
            result.push_back(i+1);
            result.push_back(j+1);
            result.push_back(image1[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


for (auto x : result)
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
std::cout << endl;
```

> Output:
>
> 1 2 3 3 2 255 4 1 255 5 2 255

http://ideone.com/yJawu5